# How to enable interaction in imageview on animation completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I am using `CABasic` animation to move an `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` is not detecting touches now how to enable user interaction after the completion of animation?

```
[ImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimation.duration=1;
theAnimation.repeatCount=1;
theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;

theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.view.frame.size.width/2];

theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"finished");
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}];
[ImageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"slide"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: You set `[ImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` but `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`; you should try `[ImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` instead

Comment: `[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"finished");
        self. ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    }];`

Comment: its not working

Comment: why don't you add image in UIbutton, in which after animation you can enable the button... check animation is possible here..

Comment: use self.aButton.enabled = NO/YES; and [aButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

In above code, instead of

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

use this

```
ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This.

```
BOOL animationPause;

ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 300, 100, 100)];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ImageViewClicked)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [ImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [self.view addSubview:ImageView];

    ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"earth.jpeg"];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
             ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(ImageView.frame.origin.x, ImageView.frame.origin.y+i+5, ImageView.frame.size.width, ImageView.frame.size.height)  ;
            if (i==4) {
                ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            }
if (animationPause == YES)
                [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateStop)];
            else
                [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(Resume)];
        }

        }
    }];
```

There is no need to use `CABasicAnimation` Actually in your scenario your image view having some frame initially and you have added gesture or something. Right when  you animate your image will go x or y based on animation requirement. an dyour imageView frame having still at initial frame. so your click event Method will called.

But yes when you click on particular frame whether there is imageView or not you will notice your method will called.

You have manage **animationPause** for pausing and resuming animation.
Hope it will work. if you still any query let me inform

Comment: Actually I want to pause and resume animation.. is it possible in your code?

Comment: you can do it man. just require some logic where you want to pause or resume. and yes you can do using this code also. But if you want to use your code don't worry just change your imageView frame when you do animation.

Comment: i hope you got it

Comment: Your welcome if ithis answer is right then please tick mark above. so other will also get use of it.